# How can one hide some text from being published by the org-publish-* functions?

Tags: org-mode

I would like to put some text into an org file that will not be published when I export the content to one of the target types (HTML in this case).  Is there a way I can accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[COMMENT lines dont get exported](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Comment-lines).  They also display purple in the emacs with default config.

Answer (score 4):

You likely want to use the `:noexport:` tag as described in the manual under [Selective Export](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Selective-export).

The only real limitation here is that you have to have the (sub)heading as the last one at that level.

Alternately you could use inline tasks ( `(require 'org-inlinetask)` ) and then mark the task and the end-of-task with `:noexport:` (I tested and with only one it might not properly omit the end of the task).

Comment: also, [COMMENT lines dont get exported](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Comment-lines)

Comment: malcook: please provide your comment in the form of an answer and I will accept it.  It is simple and accomplishes my goal.